# How to use document listener to identify changes in the active eclipse editor window?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin to monitor user activity. I need to notify the user if he/she has been idle for a certain amount of time. So I am thinking of using a document listener to check for changes in the active eclipse editor window. But most of the example code on the web seems to be using a separate textField.

```
textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.addActionListener(new MyTextActionListener());
    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
    textField.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Field");

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
    textArea.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Area");
```

How can I use a document listener or any other event listener in an eclipse plugin to listen to the active editor window for changes?

Comment: All the code you show here is for the Java Swing GUI. Eclipse uses SWT which is a completely different GUI and doesn't use that document listener. The user could also be doing lots of other things in Eclipse rather than typing in the main editor - setting up Preferences for example.

Comment: @greg-449, Yes, you're right! I also intend to use _MouseListener_ to check whether the user is active. I found in one of the threads that using a _KeyListener_ is 'dangerous', and suggested to use a _DocumentListener_ instead.